# Can I calculate the billing price from the services.skus.list method?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I need to calculate the billing of particular resource in gcp and I could't find an API to achieve this,and find some pricingInfo from the response of services.skus.list method. Can I use this info to calculate the price of that skew...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what it's meant to be used. From the doc of [PricingInfo](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list#pricinginfo)

> Represents the pricing information for a SKU at a single point of time.

Comment: But how can we find the usage details of particular sku..? We will get the pricing info, and we need the consumption unit to calculate the resource usage.

Comment: It contains [PricingExpression](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list#PricingExpression) which contain the formula to calculate them